# Zope ftp-upload error with non-ascii filenames

Tags: ftp, zope, non-ascii-characters

When I try to upload files with non-ascii characters (like German umlauts) to Zope (into the ZODB) via FTP, I get the following error-message:

```
ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1351502922.570.290289062967 http://0.0.0.0:8021/Zope2/websites/O%CC%88su%CC%88ra%CC%88ich.png/PUT
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module webdav.NullResource, line 173, in PUT
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 325, in _setObject
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 97, in checkValidId
BadRequest: The id "Ösüräich.png" contains characters illegal in URLs.
```

This makes sense. However, I'm using a PUT_factory so that the uploaded files will be added to the ZODB as one of my custom object-types. In the `__init__` of this class, I change the filename to a string that is a valid id in Zope. I've set `self.__name__` and self.id to this string, but the error remains.

For debugging, I raise an Exception in the last line of my `__init__`

```
raise Exception, self.id
```

which gives me the correct valid id. But when I remove this last line, I'm again getting the error above. Obviously, the new object is not created (the manage_afterAdd method is not called).

Is there a way to get around this, or is it a limitation of Zope that I have to live with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are stuck, I'm afraid. The `__name__` of the object being uploaded is ignored altogether.

What happens is this:

- A [`webdav.NullResource.NullResource`](http://svn.zope.org/Zope/trunk/src/webdav/NullResource.py?rev=115280&view=markup) object is instantiated by the publisher
- This object's [`.PUT()` method] is called.
- The following code, part of that method, creates the object and stores it on the parent (simplified):

  ```
  factory = getattr(parent, 'PUT_factory', self._default_PUT_factory )
  ob = factory(name, typ, body)
  if ob is None:
      ob = self._default_PUT_factory(name, typ, body)

  # Verification it can be added here

  self.__parent__._setObject(name, ob)
  ```

As you can see the `name` variable is not updated.

You could file an [issue in the tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope/) requesting that `__name__` is consulted there.

Comment: Thanx! I'll file the issue and try to live with it for the moment :)